# Ruby - `block in initialize': undefined method

Tags: ruby

I got an error

> block in initialize: undefined method `SIGN' for Mineral:Class (NoMethodError)

How can I fix it?

```
 require "./mineral"

    .
    .
    .
    @map[x][y] = Mineral.SIGN
```

My class:

```
class Mineral
  attr_accessor :x, :y, :cost, :SIGN
  @@SIGN = "s"
  def initialize(x, y)
    @x,@y = x,y
    @cost = rand 10
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a `getter` method to access the class variables in class Mineral. The `attr_accessor` method does automatically define the getter and setter method for `x`, `y`, `cost` instance variables but there is no such facility for class variable.

Besides, if `@@SIGN` is not a constant (expected to change at run-time), then I suggest that you use `@@sign` instead of `@@SIGN`. Because, all capital named variables are constants in ruby - will raise error if attempted to change at run-time.

```
class Mineral
attr_accessor :x, :y, :cost
@@sign = "s"
def initialize(x, y)
    @x,@y = x,y
    @cost = rand 10
end

def self.get_sign
    @@sign
end
end
```

Further, you can access the `@@sign` as:

```
require "./mineral"

    .
    .
    .
    @map[x][y] = Mineral.get_sign
```

From your question it feels that you will benefit by clearing concepts of class and instance variables and methods in ruby. A good starting point is [this](http://thoughts.codegram.com/understanding-class-instance-variables-in-ruby/).

Comment if you still have doubt or confusion, will be glad to clear it.

Hope it helps : )

Comment: “`@@SIGN` constant”—`@@SIGN` is by no means a constant here.

Comment: @mudasobwa if `@@SIGN` is not constant, he shouldn't name that variable with all capitals. Because in ruby variables with all capitals are considered constants. So I suggest he use `@@sign` instead of `@@SIGN` in that case.

Comment: One might or might not follow ruby conventions. `SIGN` is implicitly declared as constant, while neither `@SIGN` instance var, nor `@@SIGN` class var, nor even method `def SIGN` are not. Even more: there are many methods in Ruby core, defined mostly on `Kernel`, that are named with first capital letter: `Integer()`, `Array()` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Will `@@SIGN` change during runtime of the program?

If it *will change*: You might want to follow Ruby conventions and use a lowercase name for this kind of class-hierarchy variable. Furthermore you will need to have a getter method (and perhaps a setter):

```
# in your model
@@sign = 's'
def self.sign
  @@sign
end

# usage
@map[x][y] = Mineral.sign
```

If it *will not change* use a constant instead of class-hierarchy variable:

```
# in your model
SIGN = 's'

# usage
@map[x][y] = Mineral::SIGN
```